# Assigning a session object to an Angular object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

I've created an Angular app that stores data in the browser session. The value of one of those keys happens to be an stringified key:value object. `key:"{key:value, key:value, ...}"`

When I return the string from sessionStorage I parse it to recreate the object using `JSON.parse` or `angular.fromJson` (both have the same results) and store it as a variable. I can `console.log` it at this point and clearly see the JSON object, in all its glory -- exactly as I expect it. When I assign this object as an angular variable it assigns the object itself, not the key:values.

```
var myParsedObj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('my_object_string'));
  console.log(myParsedObj); // returns Object {key:value, key:value, ...}
$scope.myParentObject.myObject = myParsedObj;
  console.log($scope.myParentObject.myObject); // returns [object Object]
$scope.myObject = myParsedObj;
  console.log($scope.myObject); // returns Object {key:value, key:value, ...}
```

Compounded on that is that when I set the $scope to be myParsedObj it also inexplicably sets the sessionStorage item, which also becomes [object Object].

Furthermore, if myParentObject is removed and myObject is attached directly to the $scope, it works fine and binds the data correctly. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround I can employ? I've tried using angular.forEach as well as angular.extend without any success.

Comment: You can expand on that `object Object` inside the console, it will certainly have what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't though. It appears to be returning it as a string. Like what an alert() would do. There's no way to expand it.

Comment: Hmm...what browser are you using? You should be able to expand it

Comment: You do realized that my first comment on there is the output right? An Object with key:values. That is expandable. The second comment, a string, is not expandable.

Comment: Yes I see that, I don't believe that is actually a string tho, I think it's just alerting you that it is in fact an object. Try logging a key you know is in that object, see if anything comes up

Comment: undefined. Honestly, if it weren't I never would have even know this was an issue.

Comment: Indeed. Pretty sure it's a bug

Comment: That's what's getting me, I have an Angular app right now where I do the exact same thing, and it's working.